# Pattern classificaton using neural network learning

Tags: classification, matlab, neural-networks, pattern-recognition, fuzzy

[Paper1 (freely available)](http://www.jofcis.com/publishedpapers/2012_8_10_4007_4016.pdf) and [Paper2 (Springer)](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-03220-2_12#page-1) talk about application of fuzzy cognitive map (FCM) for pattern classification. I am having a tough time to understand how the equation of FCM is constructed from a set of features. My application is in cognitive vision and I have features which are (hue values, SURF features) of an object that is being identified. How do I apply FCM equation  for pattern classification ? In these papers they have genetic algorithm as the learning technique. I need to apply neural network for learning and then use mean square error between the actual FCM and the simulated FCM. I simply cannot understand how to transform the features into nodes and construct the edges.

An illustration with an example will be really helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From the linked paper (Paper #1)

> Each chromosome is defined as a floating-point vector, whose length corresponds
>   to the number of variable in a certain problem. Each element in a vector is
>   called as a gene and each chromosome consists of $N(N-1)$ genes, which are
>   floating point numbers in the range $[-1, 1]$. When computing the **FCM**
>   classifier's adjacent matrix, each gene stands for a non-zero weight value
>   in matrix.

So in other words, the graph is composed of chromosomes. Specifically, each chromosome is considered to be a node, with entries which describes the edge weight to other nodes, so you may form an adjacency matrix from this data. Note that these entries are nonzero, so we have a complete graph, complete digraph if the **FCM** matrix $A$ is symmetric.

As you'll read in the paper, the matrix is randomly generated. To find the best method for representing your specific features as nodes and how to determine the edge weighting, you should consult the existing literature in your field, this is merely an example. It may also be of interest to investigate how you are currently representing your data, you may already have a suitable structure hidden in your current representation.

Are you working in a narrow domain? It is possible that a Character Recognition problem would entail an entirely different representation to a Face Recognition problem. Specifically considering your problem will aid in finding the best representation. Consider the objects themselves, and the possible relation between them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In the paper where each node is a feature, then does it mean n number of feature vectors=n number of nodes and each feature vector is of length T, where length means number of sample points?Then for training, will I be using the weights of the edges?Each node also has a value attached to it. How do I determine such values?

Comment: Typically, the sample points are actually in one-to-one relationship with the nodes. Then, the entries for each vector (node) describe the relationship between the given node and the others. That's why in the above example, there are $N(N - 1)$ entries in the vector, we describe the weights to all other nodes in the graph aside from the node itself. The values are determined by what problem you actually want to solve, which you haven't stated concretely yet. Pattern recognition would require you to represent some defining characteristics such that you can recover this from the weights.

Comment: I have feature sets such as (hue,shape,size) of 2 objects and I want to use FCM for classification. FCM needs membership function. What I do not follow is how to represent and construct a FCM model. The learning of the weights can be done using Genetic algoritm or Neural network. Will it be possible to illustrate with an example to show what will the inputs to the nodes be, membership function and how to classify using such graphical model?Thank you for continued replies.